# What is the most efficient way of merging arrays of values in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, performance

I have a slightly theoretical question, but with a very practical requirement.

I am trying to find the most efficient way of merging n arrays of equal size based on a number of factors. This needs to be highly performant. Arrays are all 512 bytes, and will be evaluated at 40fps.

Rules (in order):
Active must be true
Highest priority always wins
Max size

Resulting array is 512 x UInt8 values.

```
struct Slot {
   var size: UInt8
   var priority: UInt8
   var active: Bool
}

let source1 = [Slot(size: 0, priority: 100, active: true), Slot(size: 20, priority: 150, active: true), Slot(size: 150, priority: 100, active: true)]
let source2 = [Slot(size: 10, priority: 150, active: false), Slot(size: 40, priority: 100, active: true), Slot(size: 200, priority: 100, active: true)]
let source3 = [Slot(size: 20, priority: 200, active: false), Slot(size: 10, priority: 100, active: false), Slot(size: 30, priority: 100, active: true)]


// result expected [0, 20, 200]
```

I stress this is all about performance, it doesn't matter how pretty the resulting code might be.

Here is what I am looking for as a for in loop:

```
struct Slot {
   var size: UInt8
   var priority: UInt8
   var active: Bool
}

let source1 = [Slot(size: 0, priority: 100, active: true), Slot(size: 20, priority: 150, active: true), Slot(size: 150, priority: 100, active: true)]
let source2 = [Slot(size: 10, priority: 150, active: false), Slot(size: 40, priority: 100, active: true), Slot(size: 200, priority: 100, active: true)]
let source3 = [Slot(size: 20, priority: 200, active: false), Slot(size: 10, priority: 100, active: false), Slot(size: 30, priority: 100, active: true)]

let sources = [source1, source2, source3]

var resultingArray = [UInt8]()

// loop through each array index
for index in 0...2 {

   let slots = sources.map { $0[index] }
   let activeSlots = slots.filter { $0.active }

   let sortedSlots = activeSlots.sorted {
      if $0.priority != $1.priority {
         return $0.priority > $1.priority
      } else {
        return $0.size > $1.size
      }
   }

    resultingArray.append(sortedSlots[0].size)

}

print(resultingArray)
```

Comment: If it's about performance, have you considered using a lower-level language?

Comment: What have you attempted so far in order to do this?

Comment: Your code sample doesn't compile.

Comment: Also, your expected result is an array of integers... You are sorting Slots, not integers. Why are you expecting integers as a result of sorting Slots?

Comment: All I need at the end is the resulting winning 'size' value. I have tried a number of way of doing this in various applications, but currently mostly using a for in loop to analyse each item.

Comment: If you want this to be really performant why do you use `flatMap`, `filter`, `sorted`, `append` in the first place? Can't you just use two simple `for` loops?

Comment: Everything I have read says that the functional API is often more performant, because it avoids unnecessary allocation in many instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on my understanding of your comments, the best you can possibly do is a linear pass through each array to find the "winning" slot, then extract the sizes. No sorting necessary.

```swift
extension Slot: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Slot, rhs: Slot) -> Bool {
        !lhs.active && rhs.active ||
        lhs.active == rhs.active && (
            lhs.priority < rhs.priority ||
            lhs.priority == rhs.priority && lhs.size < rhs.size
        )
    }
}

let sizes = zip(source1, zip(source2, source3))
        .map { max(max($0, $1.0), $1.1).size }
```

Which, with the given values would produce:

```
[0, 20, 200]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to give this and run some tests against it to see how it performs. To give a bit of context, this is all about merging E1.31 sACN data. One of my applications which does this currently drops down to c++, because it was written in very early Swift days, when I just couldn't get the performance I needed. I was keen to see what the most efficient way might be in Swift 5.2 as there have been significant performance improvements over time.

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have looked a bit closer. I see this results in a flat map of all items. What I want is just the winning 'size' value from each matched array index. If you think this is probably the best approach, I can easily refactor this to do what I want to do.

Comment: I see... I updated my answer for the new information.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid that's not quite the value I am expecting. The result in the original code sample:

// result expected [0, 20, 200]

I'll amend the original question with a for in loop example.

Comment: I have updated the original question to show exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: The sample loop that is supposed to show "exactly what you are looking for" doesn't compile. I can't know what you are looking for based on code that doesn't work.

Comment: Couple of minor issues. I have updated it. This compiles in a Playground.

Comment: Okay, now I get it! That's a way different algorithm than what I thought you wanted. The answer is updated.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry, that was my fault for not being clear enough originally! I actually already have the same slot Comparable in my real application. I don't think I've ever actually used Zip before, it hasn't really been on my radar, that's incredibly concise!